# When do identities about Directional Derivatives hold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In multivariable calculus, let $f_{\vec{u}}(X)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(X+t\vec{u})-f(X)}{t}$. All inputs are vectors and outputs are constants.

Are the following true in general? Can you construct counterexamples with everything being defined?

1. $f_{\vec{u}+\vec{v}} = f_{\vec{u}}+f_{\vec{v}}$ as long as all derivatives are defined.

I know how to prove this if $f_{\vec{u}}(x)$ or $f_{\vec{v}}(x)$ are continuous

2. $\lim_{t\to 0} \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{f(x+t\vec{u}+s\vec{v})-f(x+t\vec{u})-f(x+s\vec{v})+f(X)}{st} = \lim_{s\to 0} \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t\vec{u}+s\vec{v})-f(x+t\vec{u})-f(x+s\vec{v})+f(X)}{st}$

In otherwords, does $f_u(f_v) = f_v(f_u)$ always hold or not? I know they are okay when $f_u(f_v)$ is continuous

Answer (score -2):

I will use the more traditional notation $\mathrm D_\boldsymbol u:=\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla$.
Your questions are as follows:

- Is it true that $\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u+\boldsymbol v}=\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}+\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}$?
- Is $\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}\circ \mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}=\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol 
   v}\circ \mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}$?

---

First one: We want to show that for a scalar $\phi$ that
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u+\boldsymbol v}(\phi)=\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}\phi+\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  v}\phi$$
This is very straightforward.
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  u+\boldsymbol v}\phi:=\big((\boldsymbol u+\boldsymbol v)\cdot\nabla\big)\phi$$
By linearity of the dot product,
$$=\big(\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla+\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\big)\phi \\ =\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\phi+\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\phi\\=\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}\phi+\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\phi$$
$\blacksquare$

---

Second one: We want to see if we can commute directional derivatives. That is,
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\phi\overset{?}{=}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}\phi$$

Let's expand and see.
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  u}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  v}\phi=\boldsymbol  u\cdot\nabla(\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\phi) \\ =\boldsymbol u\cdot\big(\nabla\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\phi+\boldsymbol v\cdot\Delta\phi\big)$$
On the other hand,
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  v}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  u}\phi=\boldsymbol v\cdot\big(\nabla\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\phi+\boldsymbol u\cdot\Delta\phi\big)$$

Calculating the *commutator* (i.e, subtracting the two!) we get
$$\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  u}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  v}\phi-\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  u}\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol  v}\phi=\big[\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u},\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\big]\phi \\ =\boldsymbol u\cdot\big(\nabla\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\phi+\boldsymbol v\cdot\Delta\phi\big)-\boldsymbol v\cdot\big(\nabla\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\phi+\boldsymbol u\cdot\Delta\phi\big) \\ =\big(\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol u\big)\cdot\nabla\phi+\underbrace{\big(\boldsymbol u\cdot\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol v\cdot\boldsymbol u\big)}_{=0}\cdot\Delta\phi$$
Hence
$$\big[\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u},\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\big]=\big(\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol u\big)\cdot\nabla$$
So $\big[\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u},\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol v}\big]=0$ **iff** $\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol u=0$. So, if $\boldsymbol u,\boldsymbol v$ are constant vectors, yes, this holds.

$\blacksquare$

---

### **Remarks.**

- We can generalize from a scalar $\phi$ to any higher order tensor $\mathbf T$.
- The object $\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol v\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol u$ is known as the "[Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) of $\boldsymbol v$ with respect to $\boldsymbol u$".

Comment: Hmm I found this: (vectors are ALWAYS constant in my notation) f(x,y)=x if x=y and 0 otherwise. Its derivative in the vector (1,0) and (0,1) are both 0, but in the vector (1,1) is 1 when x=y=0

Comment: @KaiWang Ok, well I was assuming $\phi$ was reasonably "well behaved". Yes I'm sure it is possible to think of pathological $\phi$ that will break it.

Comment: Do you have a more rigorous definition by reasonably well behaved? I get the handwavy meaning

Comment: $C^1$ is probably enough.